# Missing accessory in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Before I created custom cell for `UITableView` I used this to render rows:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
```

Then I have created CustomCell with two `UILabels` in it.
And replace code from above with:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    OrderCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
```

But now accessory is not visible.
It shows only at first row and it doesn't look like before.
Is there anything else that I need to do to show accessory when creating custom cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as below. Set the accesssory Type outside of condition..

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

OrderCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil){
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


}
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

You have set the accessoryType inside the condition if(cell==nil) which calls first time..

Hope it fix the issue..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using storyboard, then you have to register your custom nib in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourClass" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier"];
}
```

If you're not using storyboard, you have to register it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomClass" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    ////

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am not using storyboard but thanks for explaining both ways :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your nib in **viewDidLoad** instead of **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";
   [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```